# How to show and hide a preference from category?

Tags: android, settings, show, preference

I'm facing a problem. In Settings menu I have a CheckboxPreference and an other Preference. They are in the same Category. I want that: when checkbox is checked, Preference (which lies below) appears. And when checkbox is unchecked, Preference disappears. I don't know what is the best way to do it. So I try this way:
- First off all: find PreferenceCategory.
- To hide Preference: remove it from Category.
- To show Preference: add it to Category.

Preference immediately disappear after removing. But after adding nothing appears. Can anybody help me?

Comment: please show some code..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a PreferenceFragment:

First you find your CheckBoxPreference and the other Preference in your onResume by:

```
CheckBoxPreference cb = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference('CHECKBOX_PREF_KEY');
OtherPreference otherPref = (OtherPreference) findPreference('OTHER_PREF_KEY');
```

now you set an `OnPreferenceChangeListener` on `cb` and then disable / enable the other pref in the listener by:

```
if (!cb.isChecked()) {
    if (otherPref != null){
        getPreferenceScreen().removePreference(otherPref);
    }
} else {
    if (otherPref == null) {
        otherPref = new OtherPref();
        otherPref.inti...
        getPreferenceScreen().addPreference(otherPref);
    }
}
```